# component loads in localhost but gives internal server error on live : joomla

Tags: joomla, components, internal-server-error

i have a simple component with 1 php file that returns data from database.
The file is called using js ajax from my homepage, and works perfectly when hosted locally.

But on deploying it to live server, the ajax call returns with : "failed to load resource.internal server error occurred 500".

i have tried giving permissions and re configuring htaccess.txt file..but all vein..

example:
localhost:1000/index.php?option=com_comp&option=raw         ---    works
web.azurewebsites.net/index.php?option=com_comp&option=raw  ---    dosent work

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the ajax PHP file directly on your live website and see what kind of error it returns, and whether it works or not.

I think the real problem is that the ajax's URL is wrong and is referencing your local server instead of the remote server.

PS: Make sure you prepend http:// (or https://, if you're using HTTPS) to your ajax URL in your code.